# A lot of "invalid command \N" when I try to restore PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, dump, database-restore, pg-dump

I made a backup of a database on my mac and tried to restore it on a computer with ubuntu.
When I execute

```
psql -U uname -d dbname -f ~/dump_from_mac
```

I have a lot of error messages like "invalid command \N" and "relation 'SomeTable' does not exist".
My question is very similar with [Can't copy table to another database with pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779644/cant-copy-table-to-another-database-with-pg-dump)
but I don't know how to fix my dump file.
I wipe my mac and can't make new dump.

Comment: Use `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20428547/238814

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427689/psql-invalid-command-n-while-restore-sql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was solved by setting postgresql-contrib package

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

and creating extension uuid-ossp in my db

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

My db haven't this extension by default and psql could not execute uuid_generate_v1() function from my dump file.
In most cases install postgresql-contrib is enough, but sometimes problem may be in some missed extensions too.

Comment: I had same problem. Since my backup had some extensions, solved installing postgresql-contrib

Comment: Just running `apt-get install postgresql-contrib` solved the problem for me after loading a database dumped with `pg_dumpall -c -f out`. Thanks!

Comment: This was very annoying. Thank you, kind soul.

Comment: For all those working with containers like Docker, using `apk --update add postgresql-contrib` worked for me.